# Where is it best to post questions about ngxs?

Tags: ngxs

I see that the ngxs tag doesn't have too many questions against it in Stack Overflow at the moment. Should I ask questions here or post a github issue [here](https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues)?

Comment: This should go in the Meta I suppose...

Comment: One of the team members mentioned that they wanted to start using Stack Overflow for questions. So it would be helpful to get an official response here ;-) Not sure what needs to go in meta and what constitutes a dev question. I thought here would be best.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way we (the ngxs team) would prefer getting questions is on stackoverflow with the `ngxs` tag. And only post issues (bugs) to github.

By having questions on stackoverflow instead of the github issues, they don't get lost when we close the issue.

If you are unsure if your problem is bug or not, it's better to post it here on stackoverflow. The ngxs team monitors stackoverflow, and will try to answer your question as soon as possible, so you will have the same attention here.

You can also try joining our [slack channel](https://now-examples-slackin-eqzjxuxoem.now.sh/) and ask your question there, but again I think it's better that we populate stackoverflow with the questions and answers as they are easily searchable and indexed by google.