# In @ngxs/form-plugin, what is the definition of the properties mentioned in the example?

Tags: ngxs

Please expand your NgxsFormPluginModule description on [gitbook](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/plugins/forms).

I just implemented a reactive forms example with `@ngxs/form-plugin`.

It works great, but it was a bit of a struggle to get it to work; because it was not clear to me that the form state *must* have these specific properties:

```
  model: YourFormModel,
  dirty: boolean,
  status: string,
  errors: {}
```

Maybe you could add an explanation of these properties and their intended use?

- What are the possible values for `status`, or is this up to the developer to define?
- What type of object is `errors` and what is it used for? It appears to be empty even when validation fails. *`errors` would suggest it is an array, but the example defines the default as an object?*

*I am posting this as a question because of your answer here: [Where is it best to post questions about ngxs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49876378/where-is-it-best-to-post-questions-about-ngxs)*

Comment: I haven't used the forms plugin yet - but I'd assumed the properties were mapped to those on [the form](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#inspect-formcontrol-properties)?

Answer (score 0):

1. `status` field is supposed to store latest status of `FormGroup`.
   You can see the code that is responsible for its update [here](https://github.com/ngxs/store/blob/70cf217a308c9813b23cd5613665c64ab9c27358/packages/form-plugin/src/directive.ts#L116).
   The possible values for status are defined [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#status).
2. `errors` is supposed to contain validation errors for the whole form group.
   Its type is [ValidationErrors](https://angular.io/api/forms/ValidationErrors) since it's supposed to copy errors from the corresponding form group.
   The code responsible for its update is supposedly [here](https://github.com/ngxs/store/blob/70cf217a308c9813b23cd5613665c64ab9c27358/packages/form-plugin/src/directive.ts#L105).
   But there's an unsolved [issue](https://github.com/ngxs/store/issues/654) with filling it with actual error data., so it's not available yet and you'll have to rely on controls' error data.